# C++: Smart Pointers & Fluent Design Pattern with References

Tags: c++, c++11, fluent, c++20

I'm trying to learn C++ after being spoiled with high-level languages for all of my life.

I would like to use the [fluent design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) with a class, but I'm worried that I'm making a mistake somewhere and sacrificing performance.

Say that I have a class `Builder`, and it has some member properties and methods. All of it's methods look something like so:

```
Builder &doSomething(SomeTypeThatCouldBeAClassOrAPrimitive &thing)
{
    // do stuff, such as
    // modify a class member
    memberThing = "something";
    
    return *thing;
}
```

And say that I'm using it like so:

```
unique_ptr<Builder> builder(new Builder());

builder->doSomething(someVal)
        .doAnotherThing(someOtherVal)
        .doAFinalThing(someOtherOtherVal);
```

Just from the code provided, am I doing something wrong, or could something be done more efficiently?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: As cdhowie noted, your implementation is correct (even if the application is likely overcomplicated). However, simply based on the context of your question, I would advise you not to mentally equate the builder pattern with fluent interfaces. Perhaps you already understand the difference, but I just figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Nerdizzle That's a good point, they are definitely **not** the same thing. This just so happened to be the first example that popped into my head. Builders are probably also a lot of people's first interaction with a Fluent-style API as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* here, but there also isn't any need to allocate the `Builder` object on the heap.  Consider instead:

```
Builder builder;

builder.doSomething(someVal)
       .doAnotherThing(someOtherVal)
       .doAFinalThing(someOtherOtherVal);
```

You could even use a temporary `Builder` and remove the variable entirely:

```
Builder{}.doSomething(someVal)
         .doAnotherThing(someOtherVal)
         .doAFinalThing(someOtherOtherVal);
```

Comment: That’s a good point considering that the builder itself probably doesn’t need to be alive very long.